# how can I get scitools to work with Python 3.3.2 in Windows?

Tags: windows, installation, python3

I just installed Python 3.3.2 on my Windows XP machine.  I have been practicing Python using both Idle and PyScripter.  I installed several packages to go with it, among them SciTools.  The installation of SciTools 0.9.0 appears to be unsuccessful - after installing (I got the .exe file from http://code.google.com/p/scitools/downloads/detail?name=SciTools-0.9.0.win32.exe ) they suggest testing it by entering

from scitools.std import *

at a Python interpreter.  I did this, and got the error

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 301, in runcode
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "I:\Python33\lib\site-packages\scitools\std.py", line 26, in <module>
    from scitools.easyviz import *
  File "I:\Python33\lib\site-packages\scitools\easyviz\__init__.py", line 3443
    print i
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The main drive on my PC is "I", unlike everyone else's which is "C".  When I look at my I:\Python33\Lib\site-packages\scitools\easyviz directory in Windows Explorer, there is a file named **init** (no suffix) and another one named **init**.p (the suffix is "p", not "py").  The file **init**.p has way less than 3443 lines.  When I open the file which Windows Explorer calls **init** (no suffix) using the PyScripter editor, Pyscripter calls the file "**init**.py", and using PyScripter's line-numbering feature, the "i" in the error message is from a list called _import_list.  Shortly before _import_list is defined are the statements "from utils import *" and "from movie import movie".  I typed 
"from movie import *" at the interpreter and got an error message including the following:

```
      File ".\movie.py", line 49
    print '\n\n' # provide some space before print statements
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

This is bad Python 3 syntax - it should be "print('\n\n')".

As I wrote this, I discovered a comment by a Python authority dated May 2012 that scitools was still a v2.x package.  That is pretty long ago in computer terms.  The person who posted the comment suggested using the 2to3 script. I am an absolute Python novice and before I try this I would like to hear from someone who has done it.

Has anyone successfully used scitools running Python 3, perhaps by using the 2to3 script?